# How to automatically generate resized images and HTML markup for the picture element?

Tags: html, css, node.js, cloudinary, responsive-images

I'm trying to automate the build process for resizing images and generating HTML markup for these generated pictures. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do the latter part.

I've used the plugin [gulp-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-responsive) for resizing as many images as I want. Though, It is not a health workflow, as I would still have to hard code the HTML `<picture>` for each of them.

Besides that, I've read about Cloudinary's API which resizes and art direct the images (a better approach than the Gulp plugin one). The problem is that after reading the [API docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload#server_side_upload) for Node.js I couldn't see how to automatically generate HTML markup (just like in [this site](https://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/)) or even download the generated images.

Answer (score 0):

You can either upload resource in Cloudinary through the API or through the UI. If you use the API then you will get a JSON response with the resource URL which can be used in the HTML. Something like this : https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method (Read under sample response)

If you use the Media Library UI to upload the resource: https://cloudinary.com/console/media_library/folders/all/ then you will see the URL once you open the image (Edit icon on top right of the thumbnail) or there is a small pin on the image thumbnail you can click on that and it automatically copies the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of answers on my Google searches, hard coding experiments and after reading some articles, It came to my mind that auto generating markup for resized images might not be the best option.

The thing is: maybe it's better to use browsers developer tools for taking notes of what image resolutions I should use in specific breakpoints and then hard code the markup. This approach avoids automatically and naively ascending resolutions with breakpoints, like that:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="./doge-280w.png" 
          media="(max-width: 310px)">

  <source srcset="./doge-472w.png" 
          media="(max-width: 500px)">

  <source srcset="./doge-626w.png" 
          media="(max-width: 575px)">

  <img src="./doge-1000w.png"
       alt="">
</picture>
```

While the above generated markup might work for some images, It won't do it for those images that needs smaller resolutions at higher breakpoints.

> If an image gets smaller at a higher breakpoint, using the above automatically generated markup would unecessarily provide a bigger file to the user, hence, ruining the concept of responsive images.

So, manually taking notes allow us to detect this kind of image and provide the best image size to the user.